# Get template ref in Vue Composable Function

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, composable

I need to get a template ref in a Vue Composable Function in a Nuxt project.

My template is:

```
// /components/Component.vue

<template>
  <div ref="element">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried to get the ref by declare it on the composable function:

```
// /composables/useComposable.js

export const useComposable = () => {
  const element = ref(null)
  ...
}
```

And I also tried to declare it on the setup:

```
// /components/Component.vue

<script setup>
const element = useRef(null)

useComposable(element.value)
</script>
```

It's not working in both cases. It only works in the second case but only if I wrap the `useComposable` in the onMounted hook. Is there any chance to get the result without using the onMounted hook?

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the ref itself and not the `.value`. You lose reactivity with that and at the time you put it into the composable it is still null.

Composable:

```
export const useComposable = (element: Ref<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    //use it with element.value in here
}
```

Component:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const element = ref(null)
useComposable(element)
</script>
<template>
  <div ref="element">
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```